# changing the font color in a computed field using javascript

Tags: xpages

How to change the font color of **Hello** alone in "Hello World" using javascript/some other method?

I tried the following code,

```
var s= session.getCommonUserName()
s.fontcolor("green")
"Hello"+" "+ s.toUpperCase()
```

where i tried to change just the color of the username alone. But it failed.

Comment: What's your goal here? Specifically, what user requirement is driving this? And why does it need to be defined within a single component? If you split it into two, this is easy: `<xp:text value="Hello " styleClass="#{someExpression}" /><xp:text value="#{context.user.commonName}"  />` where `someExpression` is a calculation that determines what CSS class should be used. Then you can set `color` in a style sheet to whatever color the greeting should be.

Comment: Tim: Just had a try if it could be done in a single one. Nothing specific about it.

Comment: Then split it into two. There's rarely much to be gained from doing things the hard way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't bother to send down unformatted HTML to the client and then let the client do the JavaScript work. You create a computed field and give it the data type HTML (that keeps HTML you create intact) and use SSJS. So no JS needs to execute at the client side:

```
var cu = session.getCommonUserName();
return "Hello"+" <span style=\"color : green\">"+ cu.toUpperCase()+"</span>";
```

Don't forget to cross your t, dot your i and finish a statement with a semicolon :-)

Comment: I tried it and it just displays Hello. 1.changed the content type as HTML. 2. Put the ssjs code: var name= session.getCommonUserName();
"Hello" + "<span style=\"color:blue\>" + name + "</span>";   ANY MISTAKE?

Comment: You wrote blue\>.  It must be blue\">

Comment: When you look at the HTML source in your browser it will tell. Same applies to Firebug

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with client java script, then you must do something like this:

```
dojo.style("html_element_id", "color", "green");
```

So in your case you can have have something like:

```
<p><span id="span1">Hello</span> World.</p>
```

Or you can do it directly if you don't need to change it with CJS:

```
<p><span style="color:green">Hello</span> World</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it is to wrap your 'hello' in a html span and then change the color of that span.

```
<span id='myspan'>hello</span> world
```

javascript code:

```
document.getElementById('myspan').style.color='green';
```

Comment: In XPages you should never try to assign an ID yourself. When e.g. you add this to a custom control you use more than once on a page (or it renders as a widget), then you get duplicate IDs which makes your HTML invalid. If you want to spit the work between server generated HTML and client side JS, stick to class names.

Answer (score 0):

Went old school on this one...

Say you want to put your formatted text in a div

```
<div id="test">

</div>
```

Then you need the following javascript to do so:

```
div = document.getElementById("test");

hello = document.createElement("span");
hello.innerHTML = "Hello"
hello.style.color = "green";

div.appendChild(hello);
div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" world!"));
```